# Loading Files from My User Directory in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Under Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sql-server, sql-management-studio, windows-8-upgrade, ssms

I'm in the process of migrating to Windows 8, part of which was to get SQL Server/SQL Server Management Studio 2012 running. I tried to load some sample data from a .bak file for a 2012 compatible version of the AdventureWorks database to make sure it was working. To do so, I right clicked on my main database server in the explorer window > `Restore Database` and attempted to mount a .bak file using `Source` > `Device` > `Add`. I downloaded the AdVentureWorks .bak file from http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330 into my user directory, however when I try to access this directory, it comes up blank:

[image: SQL Server Management Studio]

I'm currently authenticated using my Microsoft account (i.e. I logged in using my Microsoft account during my Win8 installation and setup my user profile accordingly).

My question is - shouldn't I be able to see my user directory structure? If not, is there a new convention for Win8 that I'm not aware of?

Incidentally, I was able to restore my database by copying the file to the C:\ root and restoring from there.

Comment: If you are using Windows to authenticate, then user information is not stored in the database, thats handled by Windows.

Comment: I'm not trying to authenticate to the database - if you look you can see I'm already connected. What I want to do is be able to select files from my Windows user directory through the dialogues in SSMS to load a file into that database. For some reason, I can't access my user profile from within these dialogues. I can access `C:\Users\aaron_000\Downloads` from Windows Explorer. It looks to be a bug in SSMS to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow this up, I was able to resolve this issue by creating a conventional account (as opposed to a cloud-connected Microsoft account which is what Windows 8 appears to setup by default). To do this:

1. Open a command prompt
2. Run the command *mmc*
3. Navigate to *File* > *Add/Remove snap-in...*
4. Select *Local Users and Groups*
5. Click the *Add* button
6. Select *Local computer*
7. Click the *Finish* button
8. Click the *OK* button
9. Expand the *Local Users and Groups (Local)* folder
10. Open the *Users* folder
11. Right-click in the right-hand pane > *New user*
12. Fill in the user details as required
13. Log in with this user for sys-admin-like tasks from now on

You'll probably want to add this user to the Administrator group:

1. Still on the same screen, right-click on the user > *Properties*
2. Click on the *Member Of* tab
3. Click the *Add* button
4. Enter the name *Administrators*
5. Click the *Check Names* button
6. Click the *OK* button
7. Click the *OK* button on the next interface